# Using AngularJS to retrieve data from Firebase in CakePHP 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp, firebase, angularfire

I've been working on a web application, built by using CakePHP 3, that stores lines of text in Firebase's realtime database. It starts pushing the data to the database as soon as a request is received at one of the end points of the controller. In the meantime I'd like to see those lines of text to be displayed on the page one by one.

So far, I've made it possible to deal with the request process and now I can send the data to my web page. I could follow the text being sent both from console on the browser and html outputs. However, I'm stuck with installing AngularJS on the front end, so any help on this very topic will be appreciated.

As the things stands now, since I couldn't built AngularJS, I cannot see any changes on my page when I use the line below:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.val();
```

Since there are many documentations, mostly outdated, on the web, I'm having quite hard time finding the useful information that I can use. I'd really appreciate any help on this.

**src/Template/Visits/code.ctp :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- AngularJS -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase.js"></script>

<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      databaseURL: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var codeRef = firebase.database().ref('code/');

    codeRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
    console.log(data.val());
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.val();
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<br>";
    // document.write(data.val());
    // document.write("<br>");
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // scroll to make sure bottom is always visible
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

**src/Template/Layout/code.ctp :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php echo $this->Html->css('style'); ?>
<head>
  <br>"Push the button!"</br>
</head>
  <body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to come up with a solution but I'm sure that there are many other solutions out there. It was needed to declare the application, which was obviously missing before.

**src/Template/Visits/code.ctp :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- AngularJS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
   <html lang="en">
    <body>
      <p id="demo">Push the button...</p>
      <div ng-app="MyModule" ng-controller="MyController"></div>
      <script>
       //------- Initialize Firebase ---------------
       var config = {
          apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
          authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
          databaseURL: "YOUR_DB_URL",
          storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
       };
       firebase.initializeApp(config);
       var codeRef = firebase.database().ref('code/');

       //------- Application Module ----------------
       var app = angular.module('MyModule', []);
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
       app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
         codeRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
         console.log(data.val());
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += data.val();
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>";
         window.scrollBy(0,50); // scroll to make sure bottom is always visible
         });
       }]);
       </script>
  </body>
</html>
```